# How display image from MySQL (BLOB) in JSP?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Hi I want to display an image in a JSP, and be able to handle it inside div, classs, hopefully as image ej: `<img src="image from MySQ">`.

I have the following code, but it shows the image in full screen.

```
<%Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
statement = conn.createStatement();
rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT photo FROM contacts where contact_id='1'");
try {
    if (rs.next()) {
        response.setContentType("image");
        InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
        OutputStream aux = response.getOutputStream();
        out.println("jajaja");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        for (;;) {
            nBytes = is.read(buffer);
            if (nBytes == -1) {
                break;
            }
            aux.write(buffer, 0, nBytes);
        }
        is.close();
        aux.flush();
        aux.close();
    } else {
        throw new SQLException("image not found");
    }
    rs.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    out.println("Imagen no encontrada");
}
out.println("no se muestra");%>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what you told to do.
You set whole response content type as `"image"` and then write image to the output. Instead you have to return HTML page with "text/html" content type which can look like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>My Image from DB</h1>
    <div>
       <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgWETRHHFIDIDIDCNCNNRRLKJPPDJDdjfSSS==" alt="My Image from DB" />
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

to do that you have to follow next steps:

1. retrieve your image source (BLOB) from DB
2. Encode it to Base64
3. Create your HTML page with embedded image source and send it back in response

---

BTW, there is a better way - you can put your image into file in some staging directory on your web server and just pass a link to it as any other static images. 
It will save you traffic and page load time for the next call to the same image. With embedded source whole image will be transferred each time, while it can be cached both on server and in the browser.

You only have to make a mechanism to replace that temp image file if image was updated in database (just do not change a name of that cached file).
Rest will be done by web server.

In general, when browser asks for a resource(image) it sends timestamp of copy it has in cache,
 if timestamp is the same as server has server returns "304 - not modified" and browser can use image from cache. If it is older then new version returns from server...

Answer (score 0):

This is my code :

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@ page import='java.io.InputStream' %> 
<%@ page import='java.io.OutputStream' %> 
<%
    String login = "root";
    String password = "secret";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int nBytes = 0;
%> 
<html>
    <body>
        <%
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
                        statement = conn.createStatement();
                        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT photo FROM contacts where contact_id='1'");
                        try {
                            if (rs.next()) {
                                response.setContentType("image");
                                InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
                                OutputStream aux = response.getOutputStream();
                                out.println("jajaja");

                                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                                for (;;) {
                                    nBytes = is.read(buffer);
                                    if (nBytes == -1) {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    aux.write(buffer, 0, nBytes);
                                }
                                is.close();
                                aux.flush();
                                aux.close();
                            } else {
                                throw new SQLException("image not found");
                            }
                            rs.close();
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            out.println("Imagen no encontrada");
                        }
                        out.println("no se muestra");
                    %>     
<h1>My Image from DB</h1>
    <div>
       <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgWETRHHFIDIDIDCNCNNRRLKJPPDJDdjfSSS==" alt="My Image from DB" />
    </div>
        <p> Imagen</p> 
        <a href="index.html">PRINCIPAL</a>
    </body>
</html>
```